# Multiview is not working in IIS server, but working well in my local server (XAMPP)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, updatepanel, multiview

I am doing multiview in my page. It works well in my local but once I published to server, it cannot works. I have no idea why it happens (NOTES: I've got no errors when deployed)

Front end:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Add-AssetHardware.aspx.cs" Inherits="InventorySystem_IT.AssetHardware_Add" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Add Data Asset</title>
<!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
<link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
 
    /*for tabs*/
    .Initial
    {
      display: block;
      padding: 4px 18px 4px 18px;
      float: left;
      background: url("../Images/InitialImage.png") no-repeat right top;
      color: Black;
      font-weight: initial;
    }

   .Initial:hover
    {
      color: White;
      background: url("../Images/SelectedButton.png") no-repeat right top;
    }
    .Clicked
    {
      float: left;
      display: normal;
      background: url("../Images/SelectedButton.png") no-repeat right top;
      padding: 4px 18px 4px 18px;
      color: Black;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #009999;
    }

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("li").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("li").removeClass("selected");
          $(this).addClass("selected");
        });
    });
</script>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Body" runat="server">
       
   <div class="container">

     <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
       <div class="card-body p-0">

        <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-50">
        <div class="p-5">
<br />
    <ul class="tabrow">
    <li><asp:Button Text="LAPTOP" BorderStyle="None" ID="Tab1" CssClass="Initial" runat="server"
    OnClick="Tab1_Click" /></li>
    <li><asp:Button Text="DESKTOP" BorderStyle="None" ID="Tab2" CssClass="Initial" runat="server"

    OnClick="Tab2_Click" /></li>
    </ul>
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

      <asp:MultiView ID="MainView" runat="server">

        <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">

            <br />
            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">

                <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
 Registered Holder:
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user"  Width="489px">
                    <asp:ListItem>
                             <%--see code--%> 
                        </asp:ListItem>
                 </asp:DropDownList>
                  <br />
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                  Laptop No.: 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>    

                <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                  Laptop Model: 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>
               
                <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                  Operating System: 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt3" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                  Manufacturer: 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt4" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                  Serial No. (Laptop): 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt5" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>  
              
                <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                  Serial No. (Laptop Charger): 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt6" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>  

            </div>

                <div class="column">

                <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                  Purchase Cost (RM): 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt7" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>

                  <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                  Vendor: 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt10" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                  Description: 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt8" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px" Height ="294px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
            </div>
                 
                 <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                 Attachment: 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="imgUploadLaptop" runat="server" class="align-bottom" Width="489px" Height ="40px">
                </asp:FileUpload>
                <br /><br />
            </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            <br />
                 <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="SAVE" OnClick="btn1_Click" />      
                 <br />

        </asp:View>

<asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
         
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">

                    <br />
                <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                Registered Holder:
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user"  Width="489px">
                    <asp:ListItem>
                             <%--see code--%> 
                        </asp:ListItem>
                 </asp:DropDownList>
                  <br />
              </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                  Desktop No.: 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>    

                    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                  Model (CPU).: 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                   Model (Monitor): 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>


                    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                   Operating System: 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>

                     <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                   Manufacturer (CPU): 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                   Manufacturer (Monitor): 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>

                     <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                    Serial No. (CPU): 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="column">
                    <br />

                        <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                    Serial No. (Monitor): 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                    Purchase Cost (RM): 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>

               <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                   Vendor: 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
                </div>

                     <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                  Description: 
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-user" Width="489px" Height ="294px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                  <br />
            </div>
                 
                 <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6 mb-sm-0">
                 Attachment:
                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name">--%>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="imgUploadDesktop" runat="server" class="align-bottom" Width="489px" Height ="40px">
                </asp:FileUpload>
                <br /><br />
            </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="SAVE" OnClick="btn2" />

        </asp:View>
      </asp:MultiView>

        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
         </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  

   <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
   <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

   <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
   <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

   <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
   <script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

  </asp:Content>
```

Back end (some of the code that i did related to the multiview - edited with complete code). To clarify that i did this for inventory system:

```
public partial class AssetHardware_Add : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source = localhost; port=3306; Initial Catalog = dbname; User Id = ''; password = ''");
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            if (Session["UserName"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("LoginPage_Admin.aspx");
            }

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Tab1.CssClass = "Clicked";
                MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 0;

                BindNameListLaptop();     // REQUESTOR list
                BindNameListDesktop();     // REQUESTOR list
              
            }
        }

     protected void Tab1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        Tab1.CssClass = "Clicked";
        Tab2.CssClass = "Initial";
        MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
    }

    protected void Tab2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Tab1.CssClass = "Initial";
        Tab2.CssClass = "Clicked";
        MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
    }

    // to allow connection to my database
    public void openConnection()
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
    }

    public void closeConnection()
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    // when user click on TAB 1, a "laptop" option will come out.
    //this is the list of the laptop's holder (get from my database)
    private void BindNameListLaptop()
    {
        try
        {
            string selectQuery = "SELECT ast_ID, ast_holder FROM ast_details";
            con.Open();


            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;

                //con.Open();

                DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "ast_holder";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ast_ID";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();

                //con.Close();
            }

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(reader.GetString("ast_holder"));    
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Exception: " + ex + " .');</script>");
        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    // when the laptop's holder already fill up the form (in TAB 1),
    // they will save the data by pressing on this button:
    protected void btn1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // UPLOAD IMAGE
        string imagetype = imgUploadLaptop.PostedFile.ContentType;
        Stream sm = imgUploadLaptop.PostedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(sm);
        byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)sm.Length);

        // INSERT DATA
        String query = string.Format("INSERT INTO ast_laptop(ast_ID, ast_name, ast_model, ast_OS, ast_manufacturer, ast_serialnumlaptop, ast_serialnumcharger, ast_purchasecost, ast_vendor, ast_img, ast_imgpath, ass_desc, ast_holder) VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}', '{9}', '{10}', '{11}', '{12}')", DropDownList1.Text, txt1.Text, txt2.Text, txt3.Text, txt4.Text, txt5.Text, txt6.Text, txt7.Text, txt10.Text, "@ast_img", "@ast_imgpath", txt8.Text, DropDownList1.SelectedItem);

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

        con.Open();

        // to save image in phpmyadmin
        // upload image
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ast_img", imagetype);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ast_imgpath", bytes);

        // to save image in folder server
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(imgUploadLaptop.PostedFile.FileName);
        string folder = Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded_Files/AssetLaptop/");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
        imgUploadLaptop.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(folder, fileName));

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        Response.Write("<script>alert('Data has been saved.')</script>");

        //con
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        txt1.Text = "";
        txt2.Text = "";
        txt3.Text = "";
        txt4.Text = "";
        txt5.Text = "";
        txt6.Text = "";
        txt7.Text = "";
        txt10.Text = "";
        txt8.Text = "";
    }

    // next, this line should be for the TAB 2 option (for "desktop" option).
    // The code are similar as above.
    // that's all my completed code
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;database=inventorysystem_it;username='';password=''" />
  </connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />

<pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
    </modules>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  </system.webServer>

<runtime>

    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.10.9.0" newVersion="6.10.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

  
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.1" newVersion="4.0.2.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
  
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
  
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
  
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
  
    </assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

[nothing happen when i click on the tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN1ud.jpg)

Error on the console:
(i) [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7jl1.jpg)
(ii) [Error - continue from previous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNCi5.jpg)

Comment: Where is your data located?  Is it a database?  I think the code isn't finding the source of the data.

Comment: Please use F12 to check if there are any related error messages in the console.

Comment: the database is already defined, i locate it on my server. other pages can access the database, except only on this page with multiview function

Comment: i try to check on the error message in the console, it comes out like this: SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break

Comment: As the error message, there is a problem with string contains, please post the complete aspx code.

Comment: hi. I'll post the complete of aspx code on my above post (I'll edit the post), and you may look into it. tq so much.

Comment: aspx cod is your front-end code and not others. your problem is caused by string conversion, so I need your code to debug.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I already updated the full code of front-end in the above post. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I tested your code and it works normally on my side, are there any special characters in your master page?

Comment: I'm not adding code that related to multiview on the master page. or maybe the problem is on my web.config?

Comment: I already updated the code for web.config in the above post.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error message in your console? It should show which character has the problem, and you can also check whether there are related error messages in the Event Viewer.

Comment: Hi, I already updated the post, with screenshots of "Error on the console".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the error message in the console may be caused by CORS, you can try to add the following code to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

And I found Chart.min.js in your error message, but I didn't find it in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much. I already update my code with it. But still no changes. I still cannot get why still not working on my iis server.

Comment: In your code, do you reference the Chart.min.js file? If so, please use Google Rewrite to download one and refer it.